# Algorithm used in Hashtable implementation?

Tags: java, hashtable

Does java use open addressing or chaining to implementing Hashtable?

Is one method or the other required by some specification/certification?

Comment: What's easier than checking the source? http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Hashtable.java.html

Comment: Java probably doesn't require either. Individual implementations likely do whatever they think works best, as things like that are implementation details.

Comment: You should also look at HashMap, LinkedHashMap and ConcurrentHashMap which are all subtly different. I would suggest you not use the old Hashtable class unless you have to.

Comment: See [How do HashTables deal with collisions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980757/how-do-hashtables-deal-with-collisions/4981071#4981071)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `java.util.HashMap` and `java.util.Hashtable` use some sort of chaining, at least in the implementation used in the Sun/Oracle JRE and the OpenJDK one.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [the Javadoc for `Hashtable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), you'll notice that it doesn't specify which hash scheme it uses.  This means that any compliant Java implementation could implement this object however it sees fit, as long as it obeys the complexity guarantees specified in the interface.  A compliant implementation could use chaining, quadratic hashing, Robin hood hashing, dynamic perfect hashing, Cuckoo hashing, etc. as long as the guarantees specified in the interface were met.

From a client perspective, you shouldn't need to worry about this, though.

Comment: +1 for relying on the documentation and not the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The specification is in the Javadoc.