# How can hash tables be used to store databases?

Tags: mysql, hash

I have read that hash tables are used to store databases , but how is this possible if databases rely on there being no collisions? I'm not clear in which situations hash tables can be reliably used.

Comment: Hope this can help : [Qestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730620/how-does-a-hash-table-work?rq=1)

Comment: Why is this tagged MySQL? Which MySQL feature are your referring to exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do HashTables deal with collisions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980757/how-do-hashtables-deal-with-collisions)