# Closed Hashing - Scenario when two elements have the same hash value

Tags: java, hash

I'm implementing a closed-hashing class.

I'm trying to find a strategy that will solve the scenario when two elements a and b have the same hash value, I want to search a null place for b which is not a. My trivial solution is to try to go over all of the elements next to a till the end of the table and if I get to the end without finding a null place I'll go to the beginning of the table and go over all of the elements till I reach which will indicate that the table is full. This solution has a running time of O(n) and I need to do it by O(1)

Can you help me please find a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's called a collision. Look up hash collision resolution.

Comment: Looking up at the moment. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do HashTables deal with collisions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980757/how-do-hashtables-deal-with-collisions)

Comment: Post the code rather than a long paragraph of English.

Comment: Some other keywords to search for: "linear probing", "quadratic probing", "double hashing".