# Why does increasing size of hashtable decrease the number of collisions?

Tags: hash, hashtable, hash-collision

From what I have read online, there are two ways of decreasing the number of collisions:

1. Use a better hash function
2. Increase the size of your hashtable

I can understand the first reason but I cannot seem to get my head around the second.

If lets say I have 5 keys all whose hashes are the same. Lets say we are using chaining for collision resolution. All 5 keys will form a chain starting from the index that equals the hash value. Now, lets say I double the size of the table and rehash all the 5 keys. The 5 keys will *still* hash to the same index and will *still* form a change of size 5. How did increasing the size of hash table decrease collisions?

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980757/how-do-hashtables-deal-with-collisions   [source: http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.il/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because while calculating hash it also take the consideration of array size. So while calculating hash if array size is big, it take bigger modulo value. 
Eg: 
Suppose if array size is 3 and pass values are 2 and 5 
then 2%3 and 5%3 take same place i.e. 1.
Now take example of array size 5
then 2%5 and 5%5 take different place i.e. 2 and 0 respectively.

So with the increase in hash table size , number of collision decreases. 
Hope this explanation help you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out.

The Hashing has two parts: hash function and compression function.
Changing the size of the hash table will change the compression function hence leading to the keys being allotted to different buckets.