# how hashtable collision occurs can someone explain with the help of program?

Tags: java, hashtable

PROGRAM  of how hashtable collision can occur?

I have read that a hash collision only means that the hashCode is not unique, which puts you into calling equals(), and the more duplicates there are the worse the performance.

Comment: @ Stephen C  I am not able to find the program  in the given link  "How do HashTables deal with collisions?"

Answer (score 2):

This is at least partly answered here: [How do HashTables deal with collisions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980757/how-do-hashtables-deal-with-collisions)

Collisions occur when two different values are hashed into the same slot. For example, if 2,450 keys are hashed into a million buckets, even with a perfectly uniform random distribution, according to the birthday problem there is approximately a 95% chance of at least two of the keys being hashed to the same slot (Source: Wikipedia; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).